# Задача о днях недели

Tags: java

Нужно написать программу (на java), чтобы пользователь ввёл день недели (воскресенье 0, понедельник 1, ... и суббота 6), и ещё просит пользователя ввести будущий день недели

Вот-пример запуска:

```
Введите сегодняшний день: 1

Введите будущий день недели: 3

Сегодня понедельник и будущий день Четверг
```

Comment: а и ещё мне нужно чтобы это программа была сделана с условными операторами. Можно ли сделать эту программу с оператором switch()

Comment: да, можно. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/switch.php

Comment: Какой то прямо поток вопросов "нужно решить задачу, напишите программу".

Comment: @Vennic Time for easy +n points))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сегодняшний день как считается - логично.

А будущий = (сегодня + будущий) % 7.

Почему? МОД 7 дает остатки от 0 до 6.
Как работает? допустим сегодня - 4, а ,будущий - 11:
значит (4 + 11) % 7 = 15 % 7 = 1 (остаток от деления на 7)

Если посчитать вручную. То 4 + 11 = 4 + 7 + 4 = 2*7 + 1. Недели нам не нужны (понедельник + 7 дней = понедельнику), поэтому берем только 1

Comment: Прости, но код не могу написать. Иначе этот вопрос с ответом приравняется к решении домашних задач.

Comment: Такие вопросы закрывать надо, а не отвечать на них.

Comment: @m.vokhm у меня прав на это нету. А вообще - я просто дал наводку)

Comment: а как можно сделать если: сегодняшний день: 0, будущий день: 31; ответ должен быть Сегодня воскресенье будущий среда, вроде так же как привели пример вы

Comment: @user307320 ( 0 + 31 ) mod 7 = (7*4 +3) mod 7 = 3

Comment: @user307320 правильно посчитал?)

Comment: извените я просто начинающий программист мне 13 лет, а как тут отметить что ваш ответ мне помог?

Comment: @user307320 хмм.... галкой зеленой рядом с голосами к этой записи

Comment: @user307320 посмотри вот это -https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC